# Vector subspaces F and W such that F + W = F

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $F$ and $W$ are vector subspaces of the vector space $E$, can $W$ be any other vector subspace besides $\{ 0_{E} \}$ such that $F + W = F$?

At first I thought that if $W \subset F$, then $F + W = \{ u + v: u \in F \wedge v \in F \}$, so $\forall (u+v) \subset F: u,v \in F + W $. But I'm not sure this is enough. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have proven that if $W \subseteq F$ then $F+W=F$.

Conversely, suppose that $F+W=F$. Then for $w \in W$, we must have $w=0+w \in F$. Therefore, $w \in F$, proving that $W \subseteq F$.

Conclusion

$$F + W = F \iff W \subseteq F.$$

Answer (score 1):

How about taking $W=F$? By closure under addition $F+F \subseteq F$. For the reverse observe that $u=u+0$ for every $u \in F$. So $F \subseteq F+F$.

Note: with same reasoning you can show that this holds for any subspace $W \subseteq F$.